# Pattern match using php

Tags: php, regex, pattern-matching

I have following pattern in php:

```
products/546/orders
```

The number part will be dynamic.
I have to find that pattern in following string.

```
user/proxy/products/546/orders/?cookie=admin
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: you want to grab the number from the string. Is that what you are asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to extract the number from the string

```
preg_match('~products/(\d+)/orders~', $yourUrl, $matches)
```